# Особенности использования отфильтрованных индексов в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, индексы

Создал три отфильтрованных индекса на двух таблицах, фильтрация установлена по условию `[column] <> ''`. Запускаю джоб, в котором выполняется пару десятков процедур и функций, плотно работающих на чтение и запись с вышеупомянутыми таблицами. Джоб падает с ошибкой:

> Ошибка UPDATE. Следующие параметры SET содержат неверные значения:
>   "QUOTED_IDENTIFIER"

В  [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174393.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) по **QUOTED_IDENTIFIER** есть такая заметка:

> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER должен иметь значение ON при создании отфильтрованного индекса.

Делал именно так.

В некоторых процедурах параметру **QUOTED_IDENTIFIER** присваивается значение **OFF**, может быть в этом проблема? Как связан отфильтрованный индекс со значением параметра **QUOTED_IDENTIFIER**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В некоторых процедурах параметру QUOTED_IDENTIFIER присваивается
>   значение OFF, может быть в этом проблема?

Да, в этом. Параметр `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` должен быть установлен в `ON` не только при создании отфильтрованного индекса, но и тогда, когда предполагается обращение к индексу (см. [CREATE INDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188783.aspx#Anchor_6), раздел *Отфильтрованные индексы*; обратите внимание также на другие необходимые параметры `SET`).

Внутри процедуры контекст инструкций, при их исполнении, частично определяется параметрами, установленными при создании процедуры (в частности значение `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`).

Так, например, если есть таблица с индексом

```
CREATE INDEX IX_table_column ON [table]([column]) WHERE [column] <> '';
```

и, допустим, процедура

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON /*OFF*/;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE P_Select
AS
     SELECT [column]
     FROM [table]
     WHERE [column] <> '';
GO
```

то при исполнении `P_Select`, если она была создана с `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`, использование индекса `IX_table_column` возможно. Если же `P_Select` была создана с `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`, то индекс будет проигнорирован, даже если остальные факторы располагают к его использованию.

Если же в процедуре не `SELECT`, а `UPDATE`:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE P_Update
AS
     UPDATE [table]
       SET
           [column] = 'Updated';
GO
```

то тихо проигнорировать индекс уже не получится (т.к. изменение данных нужно отразить и в индексе). В этом случае генерируется ошибка `Msg 1934`.

---

> Как связан отфильтрованный индекс со значением параметра
>   QUOTED_IDENTIFIER?

Значение параметра `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` должно быть согласовано и быть `ON` и при создании отфильтрованного индекса и при его использовании. Почему это именно так в документации не поясняется. Я предполагаю, что, может быть, это сделано для однозначности трактовки предикатов в фильтре индекса и в запросах.

При `ON` и `OFF` по разному трактуются двойные кавычки. Как это может влиять на запросы можно видеть на следующем примере.

Создадим таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE quot_ident(A CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO quot_ident
VALUES('A'), ('B');
```

Выполним один и тот же запрос с разными установками `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SELECT *
FROM quot_ident
WHERE "A" = 'A';

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

SELECT *
FROM quot_ident
WHERE "A" = 'A';
```

Запрос с `ON` вернёт одну строку, т.к. `"A" = 'A'` эквивалентно `[A] = 'A'`. Запрос с `OFF` - все строки, т.к. в этом случае `"A" = 'A'` эквивалентно `'A' = 'A'`.

Будет не хорошо, если `WHERE "A" = 'A'` будучи фильтром в индексе при `UPDATE` или `SELECT` с другим значением `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` будет иметь другой смысл, чем предполагалось при создании индекса.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо!