# При копировании данных BCP где-то видит некорректный идентификатор

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Мне нужно перелить данные с одного SQL-сервера на другой, я выгружаю данные при помощи bcp out и потом загружаю на другой сервер при помощи bcp in.

Читая логи импорта данных я в одной-единственной таблице вижу такую ошибку:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]INSERT
>   failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings:
>   'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with
>   indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

Я в принципе был уже морально готов добавить к [параметрам bcp](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=aps-pdw-2016) ещё один (`-q`), но решил проверить, что конкретно bcp не понравилось. И - ничего не понял.

В таблице всего одна строка, в ней нет никаких специфических символов кавычек, которые подпадают под QUOTED_IDENTIFIER (ЕМНИП, одинарная кавычка, двойная кавычка и квадратные скобки):

[image: Данные]

Прошу SSMS описать структуру таблицы на destination сервере (Script Table as -> CREATE To) и ищу спецсимволы в идентификаторах - тоже чисто:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles]    Script Date: 08.12.2018 17:40:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Э-э-эм, а что ему тогда не понравилось? Запись действительно  не вставилась, при этом десятки других таблиц просвистели без единой ошибки.

Загадка. Кто поможет разобраться в причинах?

PS Технические подробности. Компьютер разработчика Windows 10 + SSMS 2017 + локальная база. На "той" стороне приёмник SQL Server 200R2.

Данные сохраняются с параметрами `-w` и `-V 100`, полностью:

```
SELECT 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp '                 -- bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'                     -- database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'        -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                               -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\'                                -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                          -- file name
+ '.txt'                                         -- extension
+ ' -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb '                  -- server
+ ' -T'                                          -- integrated security 
+ ' -V 100'                                      -- db compability
+ ' -w'''                                        -- user unicode format 
FROM sys.tables
```

Данные загружаются с теми же параметрами:

```
SELECT 'bcp '                                    -- bcp
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'        -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                               -- table
+ ' in c:\temp\'                                -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                          -- file name
+ '.txt'                                         -- extension
+ ' -S server1.sequelizer.com '                  -- server
+ ' -d mydbname'                                 -- database
+ ' -U username'                                 -- security
+ ' -P pwd'                                      -- security
+ ' -V 100'                                      -- db compability
+ ' -o c:\temp\'                                 -- db compability
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                          -- file name
+ '.upload_log.txt'                              -- extension
+ ' -w'                                          -- user unicode format 
FROM sys.tables
```

Если нужны ещё какие-то подробности — спрашивайте, допишу.

---

Updated. Да, при попытке выполнить скрипт

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
BEGIN TRAN;
    INSERT INTO dbo.AspNetRoles(Id) VALUES (NEWID());
ROLLBACK;
```

получаю ту же самую ошибку:

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 INSERT failed because the
>   following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'.
>   Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or
>   indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query
>   notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index
>   operations.

А при включенном параметре `Script Indexes` получаю дополнительно:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [RoleNameIndex]    Script Date: 09.12.2018 0:40:55 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RoleNameIndex] ON [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
(
    [NormalizedName] ASC
)
WHERE ([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Зависимостей всего две - таблицы с внешними ключами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего дело не в данных и не в идентификаторах таблицы. При определённых операциях `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` должно быть `ON` (об этом ошибка и говорит). Быть может на таблице что-то висит (фильтрованный индекс или материализованное представление)? Попробуйте в SSMS выполнить `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;BEGIN TRAN;INSERT INTO dbo.AspNetRoles(Id) VALUES (NEWID());ROLLBACK;` и, скорее всего, получите ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: Кстати, _"Script Table as -> CREATE To"_ по-умолчанию не генерирует скрипты для индексов (чтобы генерировало - нужно в настройках SSMS включать _Scripting -> Script Indexes: **True**_). Посмотрите какие индексы есть на таблице, нет ли подозрительных (фильтрованных). Если нет, то смотрите - нет ли подозрительных представлений (материализованных), зависящих от таблицы (View Dependencies).

Comment: @i-one М, о такой настройке не догадывался, полезная штука.

Comment: Ну вот и причина. Индекс _RoleNameIndex_ - фильтрованный (у него есть условие `WHERE ([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)`). При вставке в таблицу с фильтрованным индексом `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` должно быть `ON`. Так что да, `-q`.

Comment: @i-one Ага, я уже вижу пробел у себя в [матчасти](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017). Не хотите перенести из комментариев в полноценный ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс `[RoleNameIndex]` на таблице в своём объявлении содержит предикат `[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL`, т.е. является *отфильтрованным индексом* (*filtered index*).

При выполнении команды `INSERT` в таблицу с отфильтрованным индексом (включая `INSERT BULK` разновидность, которая и используется утилитой bcp) параметр `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` должен быть установлен в значение `ON` (см. [CREATE INDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql), раздел *Отфильтрованные индексы*). Сообщение об ошибке как раз об этом и говорит.

Поэтому да, для устранения ошибки в данном случае должно быть достаточно добавления параметра `-q` при вызове утилиты.

В качестве альтернативы можно отключить индекс перед вставкой

```
ALTER INDEX [RoleNameIndex] ON [dbo].[AspNetRoles] DISABLE
```

а после вставки - снова включить

```
ALTER INDEX [RoleNameIndex] ON [dbo].[AspNetRoles] REBUILD
```

(впрочем, вряд ли этот вариант будет предпочтительным).

Параметр `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` разрешает (`ON`) или запрещает (`OFF`) обрамление идентификаторов двойными кавычками, но делает не только это. Вместе с этим он запрещает (при `ON`) или разрешает (при `OFF`) обрамление двойными кавычками строковых литералов. Предикат, содержащий в своём выражении двойные кавычки может иметь разную семантику при `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` и при `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` (об этом - в ответе на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566432/193999) вопрос).

Comment: Также при добавлении ключа `-q` и параметры, передаваемые в BCP нужно убирать кавычки и скобки, писал об этом [При добавлении ключа -q скрипт bcp не может подключиться к sql-серверу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/917410/213987)

Comment: @AK, да, я видел ваш вопрос и ответ сразу же как вы разместили. Не сталкивался с такой особенностью, как говорится - век живи, век учись.