# При добавлении ключа -q скрипт bcp не может подключиться к sql-серверу

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Мистика какая-то... Понадобилось [добавить ключ -q к скрипту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/917252/213987) копирования -- и тут же перестало работать - мол, невозможно подключиться к серверу.

Вот так работает:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp [MyDbName].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] out c:\temp\dbo_AspNetRoles.txt -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb  -T -E -V 100 -n'
```

> NULL
>
> Starting copy...
>
> NULL
>
> 1 rows copied.
>
> Network packet size (bytes): 4096
>
> Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1      Average : (1000.00 rows per sec.)
>
> NULL

А вот так -- уже нет:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp [MyDbName].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] out c:\temp\dbo_AspNetRoles.txt -q -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb  -T -E -V 100 -n'
```

Выдаёт странную ошибку:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot
>   open database "[MyDbName]" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login
>   failed for user 'DomainName\AK'.
>
> NULL

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулся на [топик в технете](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/ru-RU/7dbfe22a-56b4-48c2-bbc5-c25b4941aad0/bcp-out-fails-when-using-q-quoted-identifier?forum=sqldataaccess) в котором рассказывается о недокументированной особенности работы ключа `-q`:

> I investigated this, and it turns out that there some behaviour with
>   -q that is not documented. It appears that when ou specify -q, bcp analyses the object name and wrapes each components in brackets -
>   regardless of whether the brackets are there alerady. Thus, you need
>   to remove the brackets to get it work.
>
> I tested with a table with a space in the name, and this command
>   worked:
>
> bcp "Northwind.dbo.Order Details" out c:\temp\slask.bcp -T -n    -q
>
> Note that I did not put Order Details in any delimiter at all.
>
> I'm inclined to call it a bug, but I doubt that Microsoft is going
>   change the current behaviour, as it could be a breaking change. I will
>   play with this a little more, before I nag them.

Т.е. при использовании ключа -q нужно указывать имена базы, схемы и таблицы БЕЗ квадратных скобок.

Логично, что...

Итого, сразу меняю строку скрипта на

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp MyDbName.dbo.AspNetRoles out c:\temp\dbo_AspNetRoles.txt -q -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb  -T -E -V 100 -n'
```

и всё тут же работает.

Соответственно, в скриптах нет надобности в обёртке `QUOTENAME`:

```
SELECT 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp '                 -- bcp
+  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'                     -- database name
+  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+ '.'        -- schema
+  QUOTENAME(name)                               -- table
+ ' out c:\temp\'                                -- output directory
+  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
+  REPLACE(name,' ','')                          -- file name
+ '.txt'                                         -- extension
+ ' -q'                                          -- quoted identifiers
+ ' -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb '                  -- server
+ ' -T'                                          -- integrated security 
+ ' -E'                                          -- preserve identity
+ ' -V 100'                                      -- db compability
+ ' -n'''                                        -- data format 
FROM sys.tables
```